# How to implement separate sub-menus?

Tags: menus

I want to implement two menus that work like this:

```
  Cars
 *Animals   <-selected
  Recipes
--
  Bear
 *Dog   <-selected
  Cat
```

So the top menu in the main menu, the the menu below is the sub-menu. Not all main menu items have sub-menus.

Is there an elegant way to implement this? Preferably, selecting the top menu item would select the first sub-menu.

wordpress version 3.03

Answer (score 1):

I can somehow understand what you are asking for but I think you should make this more clear. You already posted an example, but I think the main problem is: You connect some type of data to each other which is not known to wordpress.

So as long as you don't provide some hint how DOG is related to ANIMAL (okay, this looks obvious on first read, but how are those two menues connected to each other? Computers are dumb silly, so they always need hints, imagine?), the question can not be answered. Sorry.

### UPDATE:

See the [`wp list pages()` (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) and [`wp_page_menu()` (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) functions. You can make use of those in your theme.

Comment: well, i meant that the second menu is the submenu of the first. so the first menu is the parent, the second is the child. So if the fist menu had selected Cars, then maybe it would show Volvo, Saab & Ford in the second menu.

Comment: @cannynboy: How are you implementing those menus? Is that wordpress 3.0 menues? Just asking, because this makes a difference. Please add you worpdress version and the name of the theme to your question.

Comment: i'm not creating menus in the Menus section of the Wordpress backend, i'm merely making Dogs have a parent page of Animals.. etc